# WebView blank after reopening NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, webview, nswindow

I am using a WebView to display some incoming content to users in a single-window application.

There is a single window controller in the app delegate that I use to send `-showWindow:` on `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and `-applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:` notifications.

This works well until I close the window and click the dock icon to reopen the window.

At this point the web view is blank and no longer responds to mouse input, such as the scroll wheel.  The scroll view still indicates the apparent size of the document.

The window is not released on close, according to IB.

Am I missing something with regards to keeping that content around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation WebView is closed with window. However, we can subclass WebView and override shouldCloseWithWindow and return NO.

```
- (BOOL)shouldCloseWithWindow
```

Comment: Oh my, can't believe I missed that in the documentation. Thanks :)!

Comment: Oh, by the way, I don't need to subclass, there is a -(void) setShouldCloseWithWindow: method.